# Youtube API json request, I can see the object, but when I try to print to console, it says function is undefined.

Tags: jquery, json, api, youtube

Here is the call in my HTML

```
<script src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/AbrahamLingo/uploads?alt=json-in-script&max-results=30&callback=charms" ></script>
```

Here is the simple function that keeps throwing an undefined error.

```
 function charms(data) {

console.log(data);
```

}

Why does it throw an error in the console? Even though I can see the object its requesting.

Comment: show some more code its difficult to tell what is wrong. from what you have posted

Comment: No I am not, Im testing in chrome and firefox.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5159428   - link to HTML

Comment: please edit the question and add the relevant code parts in it

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5159433   link to script

Comment: You asking for more code, the code i have provide is the refrence URL with the callback, and the function call back.  I dont know what else you want, so I linked the files.. They are small.

Comment: have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D6JXX/4/

Comment: Im trying to figure out, why when I callback 'charms'  it is coming up undefined.

Comment: @Dakait if you follow your fiddle link, right click in the javascript window, and inspect element.  Then navigate to your console.  You will see the error I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have done with it .. If it's correct then mark as Right :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/AbrahamLingo/uploads?alt=json&callback=?';

var videoURL= 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
$.getJSON(playListURL, function(data) {
var list_data="";
$.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
var url = videoURL + videoID;
var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ videoID +"/hqdefault.jpg";
 alert(feedTitle);
});
});

</script>
```

Demo link :- http://jsfiddle.net/7gq6Y/

Comment: Thank you very much.  Can I ask if you know why it was throwing the error? I am still interested in understanding what was wrong :)

Comment: as per my knowldge if you are using Json to retrive the data from Youtube u need to specify 
 $.getJSON(playListURL, function(data) {
 
 });
 
 This is standard format of Json